# Open Google Map from link

Tags: android, html, angularjs, url, android-webview

I'm developing a WebApplication (using Angular). In that application there is a link that should open the navigator.
On a desktop browser it opens googlemaps and on Android it should opens the Google Maps app.

This is my code:

```
var intent = 'intent://maps.google.it/maps?es_sm=91&biw=120&bih=213&um=1&ie=UTF-8&fb=1&gl=it&geocode=KQv869mUnXhHMWOijqSFOTSc&daddr={0}&gmm=CgIgAQ%3D%3D&entry=s#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;end'.format(this.plussizeAddress(address));
            var win = window.open(intent, '_blank');
            win.focus();
```

It works on chrome but using the Android WebView I get an error *net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME*

Is there a way to open is correctly even on a WebView?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe  DUPLICATE. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674941/launch-maps-from-within-android-webview